# Using the Deezer SDK with requirejs

Tags: requirejs, amd, deezer

We are restructuring our front-end using Backbone and requirejs. Is is possible to use the Deezer js script with requirejs, or do we need to import the script globally?

Comment: Did you investigate at all before asking here?

Comment: @kryger for your info, this is where Deezer support directs you to ask questions, instead of sending them an email. So that if a question is answered, people looking for an answer in the future can find the response quicker. Next time before being a dick, make some investigations yourself first.

Comment: We never try to load the SDK this way, but I presume it will not work properly. You can try if you want, but I can not guarantee you no side effects.

Comment: They don't seem to offer public downloads of their code so there's a very slim chance of getting help from the community. Questions posted on SO should still conform to the SO rules (and telling someone that's he's "being a dick" is considered slightly offensive)

Comment: Oh, and [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @Fred_Dzr thanks Fred, we have got it to work but with a few workarounds, just wanted to know if there was a clear way.

Comment: @kryger we have got it to work with shim, but needed to define a global variable in the process for the whole SDK functionality to work, which I do not like. We were looking for a more clear way. And speaking of offensive, your first comment is offensive, you could make your point in a much more constructive way. Such behavior is making people reluctant to ask questions here.